# Display a single cell value into a Merge Cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge, cell, display

I'm Having issues trying to Display data in one cell to a Merged cell.

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that giving me a headache

```vb
Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(4, 553)).MergeArea.Value = Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 9), Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 39)).Value
```

Comment: You need to join the data from `Sheet6` somehow. Can you provide sample data and the expected result?

Comment: It's basically pulling information from sheet 6 to Merged cell MO4:NB4, more like copy and paste. However it's searching sheet 6 for a value and then finding it on sheet 6 and displaying/pasting it to Merged range on sheet 1.

Comment: 'Attendance Tracker
Set rng = Sheet3.Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Names, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    On Error Resume Next
    rownumber = rng.Row Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(4, 553)).MergeArea.Value = Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 9), Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 39)).Value

Comment: The problem is that `Sheet6.Range(Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 9), Sheet6.Cells(rownumber, 39)).Value` is the value of a multi-cell range, which is actually an array. You can't store this array in a single cell. Can you [edit] your question with sample data and the expected result?

Comment: Hmm. Rereading your comments, it sounds like `MO4:NB4` shouldn't be merged at all.